# backing up database in visual studio c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am developing a windows application using c# and inbuilt SQL Server on Visual Studio 2010.

I am trying to create a click event to backup database to a specified location, but when I am running it, it is showing me error that database with this name doesn't exist.

the code I am using is

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE GRTU_LIBRARY_MANAGEMENT TO  DISK = N'D:\temp\foo' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10", connect);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It is showing error 
"Database 'GRTU_LIBRARY_MANAGEMENT' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally."

I am using the same database in the whole application but here it is showing this error.
I am using the inbuilt SQL server in Visual Studio 2010

Please help

Comment: This is a duplicate question asked by you : [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861962/backing-up-inbuilt-database-in-visual-studio-using-c-sharp). If you want to provide more information on your existing questions, you have the option to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed the keyword `DATABASE`. Add `DATABASE` after `BACKUP` and check

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE GRTU_LIBRARY_MANAGEMENT TO  DISK = N'D:\temp\foo' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10", connect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like it's looking at the wrong server.  Perhaps you could swap in "SELECT @@SERVERNAME" for the backup statement and look at the results, just to verify it's running against the server you expect.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find the file you are backup to. please change the text of 'D:\temp\foo' to 'D:\Temp\foo\Test.bak'. Please remember that the directory D:\Temp\foo must exist.
The whole text looks like this: (change the 'Test' to your own database name)
*SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"BACKUP DATABASE Test TO  DISK = N'D:\Temp\foo\Test.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10", connect);*